# JavaScript timeout() not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, settimeout

I'm continuing with learning javascript and I've come across this problem

```
//let startTime=NaN;

document.getElementById(

    "start_button").addEventListener(
        'click',()=>{
            const startTime = new Date;
            timer();

});

const timer= ()=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{

        const now = new Date;
        const elapsed = now-startTime;
        const seconds = 0;
        document.getElementById("milli_seconds").innerHTML=elapsed;
        console.log("clicked",elapsed);
    
        if(elapsed>=999){
            seconds++;
            elapsed=0;
        }
    
        document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML=seconds;
    },1);
}
```

The code should run as a timer stopwatch counting both seconds and miliseconds,
however, the code runs for les than 10ms and then stops

Comment: Can you add runable snippet using stack snippet

Comment: setTimeout only fires once....so you code is never going to count more than one iteration.

Comment: You can use `setInterval` for repeating.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67033926/how-to-add-minutes-to-stopwatch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see in [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout), `setTimeout` takes two arguments, the callback function and the delay **in miliseconds**.
You function actually runs once after only one milisecond, and it is actually working properly, exactly like it was coded for.
If you want to run after a second you should change the second argument (the delay) from `1` to `1000`.
For repeated runs the proper function in `setInterval`, runing repeatedly every given time.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) for your purpose. (And [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval) to stop.)

```js
let intervalTimer;
let startTime; // timestamp
let elapsed = 0; // milli seconds

document.getElementById("start_button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  startTime = (new Date()).getTime();
  timer();
});

document.getElementById("stop_button").addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearInterval(intervalTimer);
});

const timer = () => {
  intervalTimer = setInterval(() => {

    elapsed = (new Date()).getTime() - startTime;
    
    let seconds = Math.round(elapsed / 1000);
    let milliSeconds = elapsed;

    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = seconds;
    document.getElementById("milli_seconds").innerHTML = milliSeconds;
  }, 1);
}
```

```html
<button id="start_button">start_button</button>
<button id="stop_button">stop_button</button>
<div id="seconds"></div>
<div id="milli_seconds"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. the code works fine, 
However I also wanna call the function on a button click.
so I'm setting a button-click listener that is to invoke the good code you just dropped me. 
help me out with this too bruh.